# Какие есть события у виджета Calendar в pyQT?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, calendar

Какие есть события у виджета Calendar в pyQT?
По типу как у кнопок есть событие clicked()
Не могу нагуглить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activated(const QDate &date)
clicked(const QDate &date)
currentPageChanged(int year, int month)
selectionChanged()
```

activated - Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда пользователь нажимает клавишу Return или Enter или дважды щелкает дату в виджете календаря.

clicked - Этот сигнал излучается при нажатии кнопки мыши. Дата щелчка мышью указывается по дате . Сигнал излучается только при щелчке по действительной дате, например, даты не выходят за пределы minimumDate () и maximumDate (). Если выбран режим NoSelection , этот сигнал не будет передаваться.

currentPageChanged - Этот сигнал излучается при изменении текущего отображаемого месяца. Новый год и месяц передаются как параметры.

selectionChanged - Этот сигнал излучается при изменении текущей выбранной даты.

[image: Обмазался документацией]

Answer (score 1):

1. `setDateRange()` - Устанавливает нижнюю и верхнюю дату, доступную для выбора
2. `setFirstDayOfWeek()` - Определяет день первого столбца в календаре.
   Предопределенные дневные константы:

   `Qt.Monday`

   `Qt.Tuesday`

   `Qt.Wednesday`

   `Qt.Thursday`

   `Qt.Friday`

   `Qt.Saturday`

   `Qt.Sunday`
3. `setMinimumDate()` - Устанавливает минимальную дату для выбора
4. `setMaximumDate()` - Устанавливает максимальную дату для выбора
5. `setSelectedDate()` - Устанавливает объект QDate в качестве выбранной даты
6. `showToday()` - Показывает текущий месяц
7. `selectedDate()` - Возвращает выбранную дату
8. `setGridvisible()` - Включает или выключает календарную сетку

Вот [ссылка](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qcalender_widget.htm) на документацию.

Comment: Спасибо, я написал ответ ниже, это тоже полезная информация, но немного не то :)

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn :)